# Origine dell'espressione "fare una brutta figura"

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

Secondo il [Dizionario Italiano Olivetti](http://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?lemma=BRUTTO100) l'espressione "fare una brutta figura" significa

> dare un'impressione negativa impressionando sfavorevolmente.

Mi è sembrato sempre un modo di dire italiano molto curioso. Sapreste dirmi qualcosa sulla sua origine? Perché si usa la parola "figura"? Potrebbe avere qualcosa a che vedere con qualche spettacolo?

Comment: Potrebbe interessarti anche: ***Perché si dice “fare una figura da cioccolataio”?*** http://www.ricciolidicioccolato.com/2011/04/perche-si-dice-fare-una-figura-da-cioccolataio/

Comment: *Figura* è una parola molto vicina a *impressione* (che in fondo altro non è se non la figura lasciata da un corpo su un materiale plastico). Se leggi i vari significati del dizionario Treccani (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/figura/) vedrai che *figura* ha molti significati che indicano l'immagine o la forma di un corpo.

Comment: Tieni conto che alcune frasi ed espressioni possono essere di origine dialettale (tradotte 1:1).

Comment: Poi ci sono quelle distorte scherzo che son diventate canone. Esempio: quando una persona tende a farti arrabbiare, si dice "tirare a cimento" (cimento = challenge, detto con una parola antica). Ma, almeno dove vivo io, la si distorce spesso a "tirare a cemento" (che letteralmente vuol dire fare una gettata di cemento). Questo perche' in dialetto locale si dicono entrambi allo stesso modo (tirar a ziment), e viene riportato all'italiano come tirare a cemento, perche' fa ridere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La *figura* è l'aspetto esteriore di una cosa o di una persona (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/figura/). Più che a uno spettacolo, fa quindi riferimento alle arti plastiche. Con uno slittamento di significato, indica il modo di apparire, di essere o di comportarsi di una persona in una situazione.